# get_current_user() returns None due to "Audience not allowed" warning in Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am receiving an "Audience not allowed" warning in my google developers console logs when trying to make an authenticated request via Google Cloud Endpoints from an Android app.

Looking through the Endpoints source code, that corresponds to:

```
aud = parsed_token.get('aud')

cid = parsed_token.get('azp')
if aud != cid and aud not in audiences:
    logging.warning('Audience not allowed: %s', aud)
```

My calling code in the android app:

```
public static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "web-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com";
public static final String AUDIENCE = "server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID;

GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(
        mContext,
        AUDIENCE
);

Grapi.Builder builder = new Grapi.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
        JSON_FACTORY, credential);
Grapi service = builder.build()
```

Where "web-client-id" is the alpha numeric client id generated in google developers console.  This service is used to make authenticated calls.

This is also the same WEB_CLIENT_ID that is passed to the api decorator in my backend python code:

```
WEB_CLIENT_ID = 'web-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = 'android-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID
grapi_client_ids = [ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
                    WEB_CLIENT_ID,
                    endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID]
grapi_audiences = [ANDROID_AUDIENCE]

@endpoints.api(name='grapi', version='v1',
               allowed_client_ids=grapi_client_ids, audiences=grapi_audiences,
               scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE])
```

It looks like all of this is causing endpoints.get_current_user() to return None, and my authenticated call to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I initialized my web client id and android client id variables in the python backend, I used backslashes for line continuation to conform with PEP8 (80 character line length) ie.

```
WEB_CLIENT_ID = 'web-client-id'\
                '.apps.googleusercontent.com'
ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = 'android-client-id'\
                    '.apps.googleusercontent.com'
```

I am not sure why this was not read correctly, but when I used line continuation inside parenthesis it worked fine.

```
WEB_CLIENT_ID = ('web-client-id'
                 '.apps.googleusercontent.com')
ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = ('android-client-id'
                     '.apps.googleusercontent.com')
```